# How to get exact battery percantage of a BLE device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, batterylevel

I am so new on developing of BLE , i am creating a demo which is showing battery status and percentage. It is working correctly but sometimes it is showing 0% , which is not correct.
Here is my code :

```
  final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
        for(byte byteChar : data)
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));

        final   int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
        int format = -1;
        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Log.d(TAG, " format UINT16.");
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Log.d(TAG, "  UINT8.");
        }
        int batterylevel = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 0);
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("battery_status", String.valueOf(batterylevel));
        in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(in);
        finish();   

    }
```

Comment: any one can please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

try to get `batterylevel` like below.

```
characteristic.getValue()[0]
```

Comment: Hello Mehul i replaced with it but still it is coming when ble device disconnected and reconnect again.